# Windows XP ad-hoc networking

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have been using a Windows XP ad-hoc wireless network to connect my Macbook to the internet. Everything was working fine until after a restart of the XP machine, the network stopped appearing in the "Choose a wireless network" screen. It does not show up as an available network on the Macbook as well.

But when I try to create a new network it shows me the network name. Creating a new network does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your wireless services are functioning ok?

You can check this by running services.msc from the run box and check if the **Wlansvc** service is running. Restarting the service should solve your problem.

[Please try the following on your XP machine if the service is allready running](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx)

Comment: Superuser should send email reminders.

Comment: they should, was your problem fixed btw?